# What one needs to know as a web developer?

Tags: toolbox

List so far ...

1. xHTML, CSS, XML, XSLT.
2. JavaScript, Ajax, JSON, jQuery.
3. A Server Side programming – C#, Asp .Net, MVC, Java, PHP, Ruby.
4. Silverlight, Flex, RIA tools.
5. Web server - Apache or IIS
6. Usability, Security, Accessibility standards, Performance, Privacy.
7. IDE, Build, Unit Testing, Deployment, Continuous Integration tools,e.g. JUnit, NUnit.
8. Tools like Fiddler, Firebug, Selenium, Watir, WatiN.
9. Knowledge of Scrum, Agile, Waterfall Methodologies.
10. Multiple browsers and O/S for testing.

Please help me to refine this list or provide pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Items missing from your list

- A revision control system such a SVN or GIT is essential.
- SQL.
- Algorithms/problem solving skills.
- communication skills.

Comment: thanks, any good pointers to improve problem solving skills??

Answer (score 3):

Problem solving skills, ability to communicate with others, HCI, and the ability to debug.

Comment: thanks, any good pointers to improve problem solving skills??

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do this in reguards to web development. But if you were willing to branch out into other parts of development study algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

You'll also need to add:

1. Database design
2. Working with databases...connecting to them, etc.
3. Some flavor of SQL
4. Search Engine Optimization
5. Usage tracking/reporting

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't forcibly put this in but graphics may be something that some people like to use for some web work, more so in terms of design using tools like Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Skill (or not even a skill, but just a good habit) to run **validating** (W3C etc.) against your artifacts.